# Probability distribution of linear combination two rvs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Reading a book a find this results:
- Assume we have  a logistic random variable  $X$ (with parameters $(\lambda, \theta)$) with pdf
\begin{eqnarray*}
f (x)
&=&
\displaystyle
\frac {\displaystyle \lambda \exp \left\{ -\lambda \left( x - \theta \right) \right\}}
{\displaystyle \left[ 1 + \exp \left\{ -\lambda \left( x - \theta \right) \right\} \right]^2}\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
The last pdf can be re-expressed as a mixture of Laplace distribution
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)
&=&
\displaystyle
\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac {2}{k + 1} {-2 \choose k} \frac {\lambda (k + 1)}{2}
\exp \left\{ -\lambda (k + 1) \mid x - \theta \mid \right\}.
\label{ffx}
\end{eqnarray}
Now, suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent logistic random variables
with parameters $(\lambda, \theta)$ and $(\mu, \phi)$, respectively.
The cdf of $Z = \alpha X + \beta Y$ can be expressed as:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Pr \left( \alpha X + \beta Y \leq z \right)
&=&
\displaystyle
\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \sum_{l = 0}^\infty
\frac {\displaystyle 4}{\displaystyle (k + 1) (l + 1)} {-2 \choose k} {-2 \choose l}
\Pr \left( \alpha X_k + \beta Y_l \leq z \right),
\end{eqnarray}
where $X_k$ and $Y_l$ are independent Laplace random variable
with parameters $(\lambda (k + 1), \theta)$ and $(\mu (l + 1), \phi)$, respectively.

Please help me to understand how the last, double infinite sum, representation is obtained?

Answer (score 2):

This is just swapping integration with summation. For any region $D$ in the plane we have
$$
P((X,Y)\in D)=
\iint_D f_X(x)f_Y(y)dx\,dy.
$$
Plug in the representation of $f_X$ as a mixture of $f_{X_k}$:
$$
f_X(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{k+1}{-2\choose k}f_{X_k}(x)
$$
(note the $\frac{\lambda(k+1)}2$ is missing because it's part of the Laplace density), and similarly:
$$
f_Y(x)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac2{l+1}{-2\choose l}f_{Y_l}(y)
$$
and obtain
$$
\begin{align}
P((X,Y)\in D)&=
\iint_D \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{k+1}{-2\choose k}f_{X_k}(x)\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac2{l+1}{-2\choose l}f_{Y_l}(y)dx\,dy\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{k+1}{-2\choose k}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac2{l+1}{-2\choose l}\iint_D f_{X_k}(x) f_{Y_l}(y)dx\,dy\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac2{k+1}{-2\choose k}\frac2{l+1}{-2\choose l}P((X_k,Y_l)\in D).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Clear. Thanks a lot!